# Websharper - resources order

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, websharper

I have a Websharper application. The problem I have is that I am using bootstrap but jQuery is always put after it in the generated page.

Resources module

```
//Resources.fs
module NCF.BPP.Resources

open WebSharper.Core.Resources
open WebSharper.Web

[<Require(typeof<WebSharper.JQuery.Resources.JQuery>)>]
type BootStrapJS() =
    inherit BaseResource("scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js")
```

Main sitelet module

```
//Main.fs
...
let bodyHome <parameters>: Doc list =
    [
    Doc.WebControl(new Web.Require<Resources.BootStrapJS>())
    ... other Docs ...
    ]
...
```

Based on what I know, I expect jquery should be put BEFORE bootstrap. Instead, this is what I get client-side:

```
...
<script src="/Scripts/WebSharper/WebSharper.Core.JavaScript/Runtime.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><script src="scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js "type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><script src="scripts/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><!--[if lte IE 7.0]>
<script src="/Scripts/WebSharper/WebSharper.Main/Json.js?h=-1274498834" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9.0]>
<script src="/Scripts/WebSharper/WebSharper.Main/AnimFrame.js?h=1056596843" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><![endif]-->
<script src="/Scripts/WebSharper/WebSharper.Main.js?h=-1021627416" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><script src="/Scripts/WebSharper/WebSharper.Web.js?h=-1800611807" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><script src="/Scripts/WebSharper/WebSharper.UI.Next.js h=-782667538" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><script src="/Scripts/WebSharper/NCF.BPP.js?h=1069861987" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

</script><script type='text/javascript'>
    if (typeof IntelliFactory !=='undefined')
        IntelliFactory.Runtime.Start();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Hence bootstrap is not working.
What am I missing?

Comment: It should work the way you expect, and when I try it in a blank project, it does. I see that your jQuery uri is not the one that is usually output by WebSharper, did you redirect it from your appSettings? Also, what version of WebSharper are you using?

Comment: @Tarmil - jQuery is redirected to not use the CDN (  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebSharper.JQuery.Resources.JQuery" value="scripts/jquery/jquery.js" /> ). I am using WebSharper 4.0.189.81

Comment: Hmm, even with that version I failed to reproduce. Note that newer releases are again released on NuGet as "WebSharper.*" as opposed to "Zafir.*"; does this still happen with the latest WebSharper 4.0.192.106?

Comment: No change with WebSharper 4.0.192.107